# Whats Best way to read efficiently from a XML Config

Tags: xml, hashmap, config, categories, accounting

I searched a lot on the Internet about XML Files in Java, but I didn't found any real efficient way to read XML Files properly.
Maybe you guys know more than me about XML Files.

> I want to read this XML file dynamically.
>
> After reading all Elements in the XML File add the Category-name attribute and the phrase-text in a HashMap.

Like this

> 1. [Shopping, Shop#1]
> 2. [Shopping, Shop#2]
> 3. [Shopping, Shop#3]

This is the XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <categories>
        <category name="Shopping">
            <phrase>Shop#1</phrase>
            <phrase>Shop#2</phrase>
            <phrase>Shop#3</phrase>
        </category>
    </categories>
</config>
```

And this is the code I am using currently

```
private HashMap< String, String > lookfor = new HashMap< String, String >();

public void readConfig( ) {
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance( );
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder( );
        Document documentParser = builder.parse( new File( path ) );

        NodeList categories = documentParser.getElementsByTagName( "category" );

        for ( int nodePosition = 0; nodePosition < categories.getLength( ); nodePosition++ ) {
            Element element = ( Element ) categories.item( nodePosition );

            for ( int phrasePosition = 0; phrasePosition < element.getElementsByTagName( "phrase" ).getLength( ); phrasePosition++ ) {

                String currentCategoryName = element.getElementsByTagName( "phrase" ).item( phrasePosition ).getParentNode( ).getAttributes( ).getNamedItem( "name" ).toString( ).replaceFirst( "name=", "" ).replace( '"', ' ' ).replace( " ", "" );
                String currentPhrase = element.getElementsByTagName( "phrase" ).item( phrasePosition ).getTextContent( ).trim( );

                System.out.println( currentCategoryName + " " + currentPhrase );

                lookfor.put( currentCategoryName, currentPhrase );

            }
        }

    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace( );
    }

}
```

The Output in the Console what I get from this code

```
Shopping Shop#1
Shopping Shop#2
Shopping Shop#3
```

Now the problem:

> I add all the phrase Elements of the XML File in the HashMap with the category-name, but only the last gets inserted in the HashMap.

If I then print out the HashMap values and keys ill get this

> [Shop#3] [Shopping]

I want to get all Elements like this

> [Shop#1] [Shopping]
>
> [Shop#2] [Shopping]
>
> [Shop#3] [Shopping]

Regards Mike

Comment: There are many ways to parse XML in Java, and the way you have phrased your question will get opinion based answers, especially on the 'real efficient' part. If you are encountering a problem with some code, please add it here as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Without it, how do you expect to us to help you? Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I will do this! Thanks.